# Asset not visible in Hyperledger model after upgrade

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I added a simple asset *Workpiece* to the [tutorial model](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial.html) between the asset *Commodity* and the participant *Trader*.

```
asset Workpiece identified by workpieceId  {
    o String workpieceId
    o Double cumulatedEnergyConsumption
}
```

Currently there's not transaction or participant associated to *Workpiece*.

I then [upgraded](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/business-network/upgrading-bna) the model. The .bna file contains the new asset, but it's not visible on the Composer REST Server. 
Upgrade on the [Online Playground](https://composer-playground.mybluemix.net/) worked ok.

Comment: You upgraded the Online Playground or did you download the playground locally and used ```composer-playground``` and then upgraded the network? Cause you need to upgrade the network locally to make it work

Comment: at first I upgraded locally, that failed. Then I validated the model online, that succeeded.

Comment: Post the details for the failure error. What was the failure? Did u change the package.json version value?